# Is $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...$ continuous and differentiable?

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know if the function $f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere. I thought that this was still a polynomial and therefore would be continuous and differentiable everywhere but the answer key says that it isn't and does not provide any explanation.

This is for competition and I have very little background in Taylor series but any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: If $|x|\ge 1$, then the series does not converge, so $f(x)$ is not defined outside $(-1,1)$. (And a polynomial can only have a finite number of terms, so this is not a polynomial.)

Comment: What is the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: Do you know how to sum the geometric series?  Do you know where the sum converges?  It is not a polynomial, which must have a finite number of terms.

Comment: The function isn't defined everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a polynomial because it has infinitely many terms. When $|x|<1$, it is a convergent geometric series with sum $1/(1-x)$, which is continuous and (infinitely) differentiable. But for $|x|\geq1$ it diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $|x| > 1$, the series surely diverges. For $|x|<1$, it converges absolutely, and hence, it has a limit. To find this, note that $xf(x) = f(x)-1$, and hence $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$, which is indeed a differentiable function. So it is continuous and differentiable in the interval $(-1,1)$, but outside of that it is not well defined.